# php sha1 encodes differently to c#

Tags: c#, php

I am aware that this is a poroblem with the different way in which c# and php encode sha1 hashes but I've been unable to find an example of the php version of a c# sha1.

c# code :

```
  private string GetHashedKey(string supplierPrivateKey, DateTime now)
   {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierPrivateKey))
    return "";

  supplierPrivateKey += now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

  Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
  byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(supplierPrivateKey);
  SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSha1 =
  new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
  string hash = BitConverter.ToString(
  cryptoTransformSha1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");
  return hash;
   }
```

php :

```
 $hashedSupplierPrivateKey = $supplierPrivateKey.gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s");


  $hashedSupplierPrivateKey = utf8_encode($hashedSupplierPrivateKey);
  $hashedSupplierPrivateKey = sha1($hashedSupplierPrivateKey,true);

    //Error here

     $hashedSupplierPrivateKey = str_replace("-", "", $hashedSupplierPrivateKey);

     $hashedSupplierPrivateKey = strtoupper($hashedSupplierPrivateKey);
     echo $hashedSupplierPrivateKey;
```

Here's an example of a correct hash generated in c#

```
      530DFA9CD08CF36017B7C781E1A8D0CEC74CB944
```

Comment: Post your plain text and ciphers from both PHP and C#

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Updated with examples and full code

Comment: Is parameter `now` set using `DateTime.Now` (incorrect) or `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get raw bytes in c#, while in php sha1() returns hexadecimal by default. You can pass true as second argument to php's sha1() to get raw bytes. Or transform to hex in c#.

Comment: In php date format is "Y-m-d H:i:s", in c# "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I'm pretty sure they return the same thing though.

Comment: No they don't. Slashes in c#, dashes in php. `"1111/22/33" != "1111-22-33"`

Comment: I've changed the date format so they match, still not working.